# How to compare two arrarys and create new array with multiple conditional statement?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a two arrays **x** and **y** with same dimensions.  I want to do multiple comparisons (or operator) values in these arrays and generate a new array with same dimensions. The new array should have the values assigned by me. Here is the little demonstration of what I am trying to do:-

```
In [1]: import numpy

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: x = np.array([5, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5])

In [4]: y = np.array([2, 3, 3, 8, 8, 6])

In [5]: result_array = [y > 3] or [x < 5]

In [6]: print(result_array)
[array([False, False, False,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)]
```

I am able to compare multiple statement and result in new array. However, I would like to replace the True with value 10. So when I try this line, it gives me an error:-

```
result_array = 10 if [y > 3] or [x < 5]:
  File "<ipython-input-21-780bf095bc56>", line 1
    result_array = 10 if [y > 3] or [x < 5]:
                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What I am expecting is:-

```
[array([False, False, False,  10,  10,  10], dtype=bool)]
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Your output is not possible, since 10 is not a `bool`. `bool` may only be `True` or `False`; or, equivalently, 1 or 0.

Comment: Is it not possible to replace the True with some values in the array? The out put need not contain False, may be 0.

Comment: Your output is not possible, since 10 is not a `bool`. `bool` may only be `True` or `False`; or, equivalently, 1 or 0.

Comment: Your `result_array` possibly is not what you want: the expression `[y > 3] or [x < 5]` evaluates `[y > 3] ` that is a list containing a boolean array, next because the first element is `True` (a non-empty list is `True` Boolean-ly speaking) the value of the expression is a list containing the boolean array `y>3` — in other words, you are not doing an element-wise comparison of two boolean arrays.

Comment: You seems to be correct. Can you give some lead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your result to integer in order to see the `1`:

```
x = np.array([5, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5])
y = np.array([2, 3, 3, 8, 8, 6])
result_array = np.logical_or(y > 3, x < 5)
res = result_array.astype(int)
res[result_array] = 10
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[ 0 10 10 10 10 10]
```

Comment: Just over looked your answer. Again gone through it and accepting as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can get close to the result you mentioned to be expecting using this:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([5, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5])
y = np.array([2, 3, 3, 8, 8, 6])

result_array = np.where(y > 3, 10, False)
print(result_array)
```

Result:

```
[ 0  0  0 10 10 10]
```

Note that there are 0s instead of Falses, because it contains only numbers